# Make matplotlib catch the labels as well

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing a project where I have to measure some operation times in `C++`, then the times get saved in a `.csv` file and a `python` script gets to that data and it draws some graphs with `matplotlib`. I wanted to automate everything, so this script also saves those figures in `.png` format, then the other python script writes a `.docx` document with the results, including tables and those saved figures. Now, my graps are showing `t(n)` - how is the time of some operation relying on the number of elements (number of elements of some data structure, like array, etc.). It pretty much looks like this:

[image]

But sometimes f.e times get really small, so we have to write a few zeros after the comma, to get to the relevant numbers, and that looks like this:

[image]

(dont look at the graph, bad data). So my lab guy would yell at me, cuz he cannot see the label for the `Y` axis. The code which does the saving:

```
    plt.plot(tempSizes,tempTimes, '-o')
    plt.title(structures[structuresIndex] + " - " + operations[operationsIndex])
    plt.xlabel("N - liczba elementow w strukturze")
    plt.ylabel("Czas t[s]")
    plt.savefig(names[operationsIndex])
```

So my question is: Is there a way to make `savefig()` save a wider photo (and if it is possible not by setting up pixels range, but just make it save as much as it should)?

Comment: The short and easy answer would be to (1) call `plt.tight_layout()` before saving, or (2) call `plt.savefig("name.png", bbox_inches="tight")`.

Comment: Thanks bro, u're awesome :D